# why spring 4 recommend annotation rather than configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

Recently I'm learning the spring framework of java. I am  curious that why spring 4 recommend annotation to set up spring rather using configuration file? Some people said that the spring configuration file is too complicated. But I think using annotation is going to the opposite direction of purpose of dependency injection because using annotation we must change our source code when something changed. So why annotation is more applicable than configuration file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the benefits of Annotations over XML in Spring are:

- Less boilerplate, XML is very verbose.
- IDE integration is easier and arguably more effective (autocomplete, Javadoc, refactorisation...).
- Typos are detected at compilation time.
- You do not need to look at two different places to find the configuration that affects one class.
- Spring Boot favours convention over configuration, so most of the time you just need to override a few things, and you do not even need an extra XML config file for that. They are following that route because it makes sense for that product and you could argue that it is good to be consistent across the whole Spring family.

On the other hand, XML has its own benefits like:

- Configuration is centralised.
- You can use the same class with two different configurations in the XML.
- You do not need to recompile when making a change.

But apparently those benefits are not enough for XML to be the preferred method. In the end, I would say it is more a matter of preference than anything else.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It's all about trade off.